# "Social Customer Service" Social Persona demographics

Tags: social-contacts, socialpost

With 'Social Customer Service' enabled I was looking at Social Persona object itself. I wondered about demographic data that is available in Social Studio (like Country, Language) but also any other which I believe are gathered by Radian 6 (Gender, Age). 
I do not see such fields on the Object itself but wondered if this is somehow passed over with Social Customer Service at all?

Regards,
VatzU

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember when implementing the Social Studio integration only the fields that are supplied in the standard Salesforce integration are available. If you need to do demographic reporting on the contacts then I believe that you can only do that in Radian6 itself.